# New command with cases / conditionals / 'if… then's

Tags: floats, conditionals, ifthenelse

I defined a command to insert figures easier and according to some college formatting. It is working just fine, but I am having a problem trying to add a conditional statement. The command is this:

```
%\figura{fig-location}{caption}{width(0-1)}{Source(if own, leavy empty)}{label}
     \newcommand{\figura}[5]{
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                \caption[#2]{\raggedright #2}
                \label{fig:#5}
                \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#1}\\
                \end{center}
                \textbf{Fuente: }#4
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
     }
```

The output is as I want it to be, here is an example:

[image: Example of output.]

However, some figures are made by me, and I don't need to cite the source of such figures. Source is the word Fuente (Spanish). So I want to modify the command with a conditional so that when I leave the `#4` argument empty, it does not print the word `Fuente:` under the figure. Id est:

- If `#4 =`, then do nothing.
- If `#4 = something`, then write under the figure `Fuente: #4`.

Is it possible to realise the above pseudocode? If so, how can I?

I found this in another post, but it only works with the exact word "something", I need it to work with anything different from an empty argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\example}[2]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {}{$\sqrt{#2}$}%
        {something}{Fuente: XYZ}%
        % you can add more cases here as desired
    }
     [\PackageError{tree}{Undefined option to tree: #1}{}]%
}%
\begin{document}

\example{}{None}
\example{something}{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\edef\tempa{}\edef\tempb{#4}\ifx\tempa\tempb\relax\else Fuente: #4\fi`? But I would use `xparse` and `\NewDocumentCommand` so you can utilise `\IfValueT{#4}{Fuente: #4}` etc.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE.**

I made it, here is the new version of the command:

```
\newcommand{\figura}[5]{
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \caption[#2]{\raggedright #2}
            \label{fig:#5}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#1}\\
            \end{center}            
              \ifstrequal{#4}{}%
              {}%
              {\textbf{Fuente: }#4}%            
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
}
```

Comment: (i) the same result as width `\caption[#2]{\raggedright #2}` you will obtain with `\caption{\raggedright #2}`; (ii) use placement option `[H]` can cause  bed formatting of document (empty spaces at bottom of pages); (iii) caption formatting I would rather leave to `caption` package settings.

Comment: BTW, the same result as with your command definition you will obtain with shorter `\newcommand{\figura}[5]{
            \begin{center}
            \captionof{figure}{#2}
            \label{fig:#5}
                \includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#1}\\
              \ifstrequal{#4}{}%
              {}%
              {\raggedright\textbf{Fuente: }#4}%
            \end{center}
}`

Comment: @Zarko tranks for your suggestions, you are right, I am  having problem with big spaces at the end of some pages, do you suggest I use `[htb]` instead? It is mandatory that the  figures and/or tables appear after they are called in the text redaction, i.e., not inmidiately below the paragrahp in with it is called, but anywhere after the paragraph.

Comment: (i) I would not use your command but rather stick with standard way for inserting figures ... (ii) instead of `[H]` is better to use `[ht]`. `H` destroy one of main power of LaTeX: floating of figures/tables and with this enable to produce beautiful documents. With `[ht` image will appear in document at point where it is inserted, if there is enough space for it, otherwise it will be on the top of the next page.